# ¿Por qué las balas en mi juego de naves se disparan lejos de la nave?

Tags: c++, poo, vscode, class

Estoy haciendo un juego de disparar a meteoritos con una nave, algo sencillo, pues apenas estoy comenzando a escribir en C++, en fin, la cuestión es que al disparar, las balas, en lugar de salir de la mitad de la nave, salen unas cuantas posiciones a la izquierda.

Estoy tomando referencias de un vídeo de youtube, y la verdad que el código está idéntico, por lo que no logro reconocerlo por mi propia cuenta.

El código está incompleto, pero solamente le faltan las colisiones de bala-meteorito, así que dudo que sea relevante con este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código:

````
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

#define UP    72
#define LEFT  75
#define DOWN  80
#define RIGHT 77

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon, dwPos);
}

void Hiding_Cursor() //ocultando el cursor.
{
    HANDLE hCon;
    hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
    cci.dwSize = 1;
    cci.bVisible = FALSE;

    SetConsoleCursorInfo(hCon, &cci);    
}



void Print_Field() //imprimir limites del campo
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= 76; i++)
    {
        gotoxy (i, 3); printf("%c", 205);
        gotoxy (i, 33); printf("%c", 205);
    }

    for (int i = 4; i <= 33; i++)
    {
        gotoxy (2, i); printf("%c", 186);
        gotoxy (77, i); printf("%c", 186);
    }
    gotoxy (2, 3); printf("%c", 201);
    gotoxy (2, 33); printf("%c", 200);
    gotoxy (77, 3); printf("%c", 187);
    gotoxy (77, 33); printf("%c", 188);
}

class Ship
{
    int x, y;
    int health, lives;

public: 
        Ship(int _x, int _y, int _health, int _lives): x(_x), y(_y), health(_health), lives(_lives){}

        int X() 
        {
            return x;
        }
        int Y() 
        {
            return y;
        }
        void Heart() 
        {
            health--;
        }

        void Print_Ship();
        void Del_Ship();
        void Move_Ship();
        void Print_Health();
        void Dying();
};

void Ship::Print_Ship() //imprimiendo nave
{
    gotoxy (x, y);  printf("  %c", 30);
    gotoxy (x, y+1);printf(" %c%c%c", 40, 207, 41);
    gotoxy (x, y+2);printf("%c%c %c%c", 30, 190, 190, 30);
}

void Ship::Del_Ship() //borrando la nave
{
    gotoxy (x, y);   printf("        ");
    gotoxy (x, y+1); printf("        ");
    gotoxy (x, y+2); printf("        ");
}

void Ship::Move_Ship() //moviendo la nave
{
   if (kbhit())
        {
            char key = getch();
            Del_Ship();
            if (  key == UP && y>4) y--;
            if (  key == LEFT && x>3) x--;
            if (  key == DOWN && y+3 < 33) y++;
            if (  key == RIGHT && x+6 < 77) x++;
            if ( key == 'e' ) health--;
            Print_Ship();
            Print_Health();
        }    
}

void Ship::Print_Health()
{
    gotoxy (50, 2); printf("LIVES  %d", lives);
    gotoxy (64, 2); printf("HEALTH ");
    gotoxy (70, 2); printf("      ");
    for (int i = 0; i < health; i++)
    {
        gotoxy (70+i, 2); printf("%c", 3);
    }
    
}

void Ship::Dying() //"""explosión""" al morir
{
    if ( health == 0)
    {
        Del_Ship();
        gotoxy(x, y);   printf("   **   ");
        gotoxy(x, y+1); printf("  ****  ");
        gotoxy(x, y+2); printf("   **   ");
        Sleep(200);

        Del_Ship();
        gotoxy(x, y);   printf(" * ** *");
        gotoxy(x, y+1); printf("  **** ");
        gotoxy(x, y+2); printf(" * ** *");
        Sleep(200);
        Del_Ship();
        lives--;
        health = 3;
        Print_Health();
        Print_Ship();
    }
}

class Asteroid
{
    int x, y;
public: 
    Asteroid (int _x, int _y): x(_x), y(_y){}
    void Print_Asteroid();
    void Move_Asteroid();
    void Crash(Ship &N);
};

void Asteroid::Print_Asteroid()
{
    gotoxy (x, y); printf("%c", 220);
}

void Asteroid::Move_Asteroid()
{
    gotoxy (x, y); printf(" ");
    y++;
    if (y > 32)
    {
        x = rand()%71 + 4;
        y = 4;
    }
    Print_Asteroid();
}

void Asteroid::Crash(Ship &N)
{
    if (x >= N.X() && x < N.X()+6 && y >= N.Y() && y <= N.Y()+2)
    {
        N.Heart();
        N.Del_Ship();
        N.Print_Ship();
        N.Print_Health();
        x = rand()%71 + 4;
        y = 4;
    }
    
}

class Bullet
{
    int x, y;
public:
    Bullet(int _x, int _y): x(_y), y(_y){}
    int X() 
    {
        return x;
    }
    int Y()
    {
        return y;
    }

    void Move_Bullet();
    bool out();
};

void Bullet::Move_Bullet()
{
    gotoxy (x, y); printf(" ");
    if (y > 4) y--;
    gotoxy(x, y); printf("%c", 167);
}

bool Bullet::out()
{
    if (y == 4) return true;
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    Hiding_Cursor();
    Print_Field();
    Ship N(7, 7, 3, 3);
    N.Print_Ship();
    N.Print_Health();

    list<Asteroid*> A;
    list<Asteroid*>::iterator it_2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        A.push_back(new Asteroid(rand()%75 + 2, rand()%5 + 4));
    }

    list<Bullet*> B;
    list<Bullet*>::iterator it;

    bool game_over = false;

    while (!game_over)
    {
        if (kbhit())
        {
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(0X20))
            B.push_back(new Bullet(N.X()+2, N.Y()-1));
        }

    for (it = B.begin(); it != B.end(); it++)
    {
        (*it)->Move_Bullet();
        if ((*it)->out())
        {
            gotoxy ((*it)->X(), (*it)->Y()); printf(" ");
            delete(*it);
            it = B.erase(it);
        }
    }
    for (it_2 = A.begin(); it_2 != A.end(); it_2++)
    {
        (*it_2)->Move_Asteroid();
        (*it_2)->Crash(N);
    }
    
        N.Dying();
        N.Move_Ship();
        Sleep(30);
    }
    
  
    //system("pause");
    return 0;
} ```

Muchas gracias, espero alguien me pueda ayudar.
````

Comment: De momento no veo nada raro. Lo que sí te puedo dar son algunas sugerencias: 1. ¿No crees que la ejecución de `out` la podrías hacer en `Move_Bullet` también? 2. Puedes llamar `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` una única vez al comienzo del programa y guardar el valor de retorno en una variable. Esto porque el valor siempre será el mismo, al menos durante la ejecución del programa. Y así aumentas su rendimiento.

Comment: No entendí muy bien el punto de `GetStdHandle` pues solo lo llamé una vez de más para ocultar el cursor ya que la verdad es molesto ver ese parpadeo mientras mueves la nave jaja. Y a qué te refieres con lo primero? Lo pregunto ya que `out` es una variable booleana y `Move_Bullet` un void, o no sabría si se pueden juntar, estoy muy verde en este lenguaje. De todas formas muchas gracias por tu comentario

Comment: Me refiero a que cada vez que llamas a la función `gotoxy` la función `GetStdHandle` también es llamada. Entonces, ¿para qué llamar a `GetStdHandle` a cada rato si el valor siempre es el mismo? En cuanto a lo de `out` ahora que lo pienso mejor, así está bien.

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en el constructor de `Bullet`:

```
Bullet(int _x, int _y): x(_y), y(_y){}
```

Debería ser:

```
Bullet(int _x, int _y): x(_x), y(_y){}
```

También detecté un error en `for (it = B.begin(); it != B.end(); i++)`.

Cuando una lista tiene un solo elemento y lo borras, obtienes un error si intentas acceder al siguiente elemento.

Se puede solucionar avanzando al siguiente elemento solo si no borras uno.

```
for (auto it = B.begin(); it != B.end(); )
{
    (*it)->Move_Bullet();
    
    if ((*it)->out())
    {
        gotoxy((*it)->X(), (*it)->Y());
        printf(" ");
        delete(*it);
        it = B.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        it++;
    }
}
```

---

Algunas observaciones:

- En lugar de tener que escribir un tipo largo o si simplemente no quieres escribirlo, puedes escribir [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) donde escribirías el tipo de la variable. De este modo el compilador se encargará de inferir el tipo. Esto solo funciona cuando declaras y asignas una variable al mismo tiempo.

  Por ejemplo:

  ```
  // El compilador infiere el tipo int
  auto numero = 10;

  // No compila
  auto numero;
  numero = 10;
  ```
- La llamada a `GetStdHandle` no es gratis, toma su tiempo. Como durante la ejecución devuelve siempre el mismo valor, podrías llamarla una sola vez al comienzo de `main` y guardarlo en un variable fuera de la función así:

  ```
  HANDLE hCon;

  void gotoxy(int x, int y)
  {
      COORD dwPos;
      dwPos.X = x;
      dwPos.Y = y;

      SetConsoleCursorPosition(hCon, dwPos);
  }

  ...

  int main()
  {
      hCon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
      ...
  }
  ```

  De este modo aligeras la carga del programa un poco.
- Es recomendable que uses funcionalidad de C++ en vez de la de C. `cout` en lugar de `printf`, `cin` en lugar de `scanf`, `new` y `delete` en lugar de `malloc` y `free`, etc.
- Si planeas que el juego siempre tenga el mismo tamaño, podrías redimensionar la ventana de la consola para que se vea bien.

  Para ello puedes usar la función [`MoveWindow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow) y si solo quieres que cambie el tamaño y no su posición, también [`GetWindowRect`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect)

  ```
  HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
  RECT rect = {};
  GetWindowRect(consoleWindow, &rect);

  MoveWindow(consoleWindow, rect.left, rect.top, 680, 600, true);
  ```